# Multiple screen support based on screen size

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an android app that run on every size screen. For this I have created folder `drawable, drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi and drawable-xhdpi`. And for layouts creating folders `layout, layout-small, layout-normal, layout-large and layout-xlarge`. For values I am creating `values, values-small, values-normal, values-large, values-xlarge`. This is first time I am working on multiple screen support. And on Internet so many links that explain multiple screen support in different ways. So I have few questions.

1. There is need of any other folder than these folders?
2. Am I doing right?
3. How to convert resolution from ppi to dpi?

And the important thing I am creating app only in portrait mode.

Edit-

First I am creating values folders with `ldpi, mdpi, hdpi`. But devices belongs to same dpi but having different sizes creating problem. So I decide to create folders like above.

Comment: Follow this link http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html for more info

Answer (score 0):

Dp are Density independant pixels and are used to generalise the number of pixels a screen has. These are generalised figures taken from

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
    large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
    normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
    small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
    Generalised Dpi values for screens:

```
ldpi Resources for low-density (ldpi) screens (~120dpi)
mdpi Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). (This is the baseline density.)
hdpi Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens (~240dpi).
xhdpi Resources for extra high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi).
Therefore generalised size of your resources (assuming they are full screen):

ldpi
Vertical = 426 * 120 / 160 = 319.5px
Horizontal = 320 * 120 / 160 = 240px
mdpi
Vertical = 470 * 160 / 160 = 470px
Horizontal = 320 * 160 / 160 = 320px
hdpi
Vertical = 640 * 240 / 160 = 960px
Horizontal = 480 * 240 / 160 = 720px
Edit - adding xhdpi as they are becoming more popular

xhdpi
Vertical = 960 * 320 / 160 = 1920px
Horizontal = 720 * 320 / 160 = 1440px
```

Comment: Please provide specific answers according to my questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
   values-w360dp
    values-w360dp-xhdpi
    values-w360dp-xxhdpi


drawable-w360dp
```

for better reference , read this thread.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

```
public static int convertDpToPx(int dp,Context context)
    {
        float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp,  context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        return (int)px;
    }
    public static int convertPxoDp (int pixel,Context context) 
    {
        float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density; 
        int minHeight = (int) (pixel*density + 0.5f);
        return minHeight;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide specific answers.

Comment: use another folder "w360dp"

Answer (score 0):

**Keep it simple silly**

You are `already aware` about the usage of `different folders to provide alternative resources` and images to the application.so just go with it.`add it` to your application.

and now the next step is,
Just design your layout files and look at its `Graphical Layout` for `Preview All Screen Sizes`.

Now,`Check->Analyse->Change if required`

And you're done :-)

Comment: And I need any other folders than those?

Comment: @JohnR: just download sample app from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html) and do likewise. you may use different folders also like `values-sw600dp`,`values-sw720dp` etc.it totally depends upon your requirement.you will feel comfortable when you apply and analyse as I have mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> There is need of any other folder than these folders?

There is no "need" to put any of the extra folders actually. Create them only if you need them and only if you want to provide a different layout/resources for the specific device. For example if you have a list view whose items open a detail view (activity) on a phone, you might want a separate layout for tablets(xlarge for example) that has only 1 activity with 2 fragments side by side.

> Am I doing right?

Can you test it now? Do you have any problems running your app on different devices?

> How to convert resolution from ppi to dpi?

Can't give you an exact formula, but you can find more info about [DPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch) and [PPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixels_per_inch) in wikipedia.